# does azure web service deployment overwrite everything?

Tags: azure, web-deployment

When we deploy to azure web service, does it overwrite all files or just the ones have changed.

I am using CICD in VSTS to deploy to azure and not sure each time we deploy, it deploys a new version or just overwrites the ones that changed.

If it overwrites, what is the best practice not to overwrite some text files and appsettings.json during each deployment and keep the old ones have already been deployed.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only updates the files that have changed (at least when doing local git\zip package\git deploy). VSTS deploy step is using zip package deploy as far as I remember.

Comment: thank you. I will give it a go and will confirm that.

Comment: it should give you an output something like: `file X was changed, updating file X` for each file changed